# How to remove surplus spaces at the end of a cell value in sqlite3?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm looking for a way to get rid of surplus spaces at the end of perfectly fine cell values. That would be all two spaces or more at the end of a cell value. Some cell values contain spaces between words. The sed command for such value would have been `sed -re 's/\s{2,}*$//'`. As far as I know `REPLACE()` doesn't support patterns at all nor backward replacement groups (\0 \1 and so on) and `REGEXP()` (from the externally-loaded library) doesn't do replacements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQLite, you can use [string function `rtrim()`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#rtrim) to remove spaces at the end of a string.

```
select rtrim(mycol) from mytable
```

If you want to remove trim only values that have at least two spaces and leave values that end with a single space untouched, you can wrap this in a condition:

```
select case when mycol like '%  ' then rtirm(mycol) else mycol end from mytable
```

Or if you are looking for an `update` statement:

```
update mytable set mycol = rtrim(mycol) where mycol like '%  '
```